# Walking with incremental weights?

Tags: walking

What effects can be expected from daily morning walks with incremental weights, like adding 1 kg every 5 days?

Starting off with 25 kg or ~55 lb. At some point, after like 4 months, I'll be walking with 49 kg on my back or 105 lb; which is around what military people carry.

But then I'll also keep increasing until I run out of weights, or eventually, I'll have to walk around with dumbbells in my hands and not just a backpack and a weighted vest.

Comment: I'm interested in this one, since I'd rather add more weight to my backpack than walk for a longer period of time, if possible

Comment: It very much depends on the terrain. If you're walking on the flat there will be very little extra aerobic demand, but on hills it will be _much_ harder. I've used walks with lots of added weight to train for hikes at altituide, as it simulates the effects very well.

Comment: I've read that incremental weights or weights you wear while you walk or run can be tough on your joints  and spine, and doesn't necessarily do much for you other than burn a few extra calories, which if that's the case, you can just go for a jog instead of walking if thats your goal. backpacks put weight on your spine, it be like holding a barbell for a squat but just walking for hours at a time, and weighted pads such as arm and leg weights can put stress on your joints.

Comment: What @AceCabbie said. What purpose are you trying to accomplish by adding weight?

Answer (score 2):

Going for a walk with a weighted vest or backpack is called [*Rucking*](https://www.goruck.com/pages/what-is-rucking), or a [*Loaded March*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_march).

Rucking is pretty simple and has lots of positive benefits. You'll definitely burn more calories than just walking alone while building strength. This [AoM article](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/the-benefits-of-rucking/) suggests starting with about 10% of your body weight and adding an additional 5 lb weekly to a max of about 50 lb.

> " [...] daily morning walks with incremental weights [...] "

Just like with any workouts, recovery is important. Daily walks are definitely OK, but I would echo most of the rucking community that daily loaded marches/rucking is not advised. Schedule recover days into your rucking programming.

Comment: I agree with this. Rucking is great, but even though "*I'll be walking with 49 kg on my back or 105 lb; which is around what military people carry*", it's important to understand that soldiers don't constantly walk around with this weight.